# Concatenate two function Parameters<T>

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, generics, merge

Given:

```
function example(foo: string){}
```

I am looking to generate a type `[string, string]` by using `Parameters<T>`.

```
type DoubleArgs = [...Parameters<typeof example>, ...Parameters<typeof example>]
```

However this isn't working as expected, I am seeing `DoubleArgs` as `[any, ...any[]]`.

How can I "merge" or "concatenate" two arrays of arguments together in a specific order?

Comment: The code works out of the box with [TS 4.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCmDjgC5EBnKAJxjAHMBKRAb0QF8AoTqAT22SIAInBAAjfAEFq9CogC8iANoA6NQAV01LMijJqFADx8BcYCgw58APgA0iNSs3bMu-UZPIzFrHmTWAXSA). With older versions, you can only have one rest element